# powershell modules missing / Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I'm trying to setup powershell to work with AWS services. First I loaded the AWS
`Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Common` from powershell then tried to import various modules. I noticed folders for `s3`, `Ec2` and `Redshift` and thats what I want. When I type `Get-Help AWS` in powershell, I don't see all of my folders. I only see folders for `EC2` and the `AWS.Tools.Common` modules, `AWS.Tools.Installer` modules and `EC2` modules. I don't think I installed this correctly.  I used the link below

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Common/4.1.237

also this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/powershell/latest/userguide/aws-pst-ug.pdf#pstools-getting-set-up-windows

I just wanted to work with my AWS services without using AWS CLI. I had Windows Powershell, but recently upgrade to Powershell Core 7. I'm not sure if there are too many Powershells on my system, but please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: *Windows Powershell* (`powershell.exe`) and *Powershell Core* (`pwsh.exe`) are different products (no *"upgrade"*). You use them independently (in particular, an enhancement installed in one of them is not installed for he other…)

Comment: Start Powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Then do the installation.